# React Native unable to resolve module events (nodemailer)

Tags: node.js, react-native, nodemailer

Hi I am trying to implement nodemailer, however get an error of unable to resolve module events. This code can be dound at: https://nodemailer.com/about/ How can I resolve this?

contact.js

```
  render() {

'use strict';
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

// Generate test SMTP service account from ethereal.email
// Only needed if you don't have a real mail account for testing
nodemailer.createTestAccount((err, account) => {
    // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.ethereal.email',
        port: 587,
        secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
        auth: {
            user: account.user, // generated ethereal user
            pass: account.pass // generated ethereal password
        }
    });

    // setup email data with unicode symbols
    let mailOptions = {
        from: '"Fred Foo " <foo@example.com>', // sender address
        to: 'bar@example.com, baz@example.com', // list of receivers
        subject: 'Hello ✔', // Subject line
        text: 'Hello world?', // plain text body
        html: '<b>Hello world?</b>' // html body
    };

    // send mail with defined transport object
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
        // Preview only available when sending through an Ethereal account
        console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));

        // Message sent: <b658f8ca-6296-ccf4-8306-87d57a0b4321@example.com>
        // Preview URL: https://ethereal.email/message/WaQKMgKddxQDoou...
    });
});
```

[image: Error message]

Comment: can you check your package.json has nodemailer? or npm install again.

Comment: yes it has! can you please try and use this?

Comment: after installing the package, restart the react native packager